# Формирование файла pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, minio

Формирую файл pdf.
При локальном формировании файла в Idea - pdf`ка формируется корректно.
А если посылать этот файл в MiniO S3 - вместо русских букв генерируются символы '#'

Сам пробовал указывать явно кодировку через
metadata.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=utf-8");
Не помогает :-(

Сейчас больше склоняюсь к тому, чтобы добавлять шрифты.
Подскажите, как мне это можно добавить в уже существующий код.

Заранее спасибо!

```
@SneakyThrows
    public byte[] createDocument(PaymentInstructionModel model) {
        WordprocessingMLPackage word = Docx4J.load(new ClassPathResource("template.docx").getInputStream());
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = word.getMainDocumentPart();
        Map<String, String> variables = objectMapper.convertValue(model, new TypeReference<>() {});
        mainDocumentPart.variableReplace(variables);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Docx4J.toPDF(word, os);
        return os.toByteArray();
    }
```

```
        byte[] document = documentService.createDocument(model);
        String key = String.format("%s/%d-%d-%d_Платёж_№%s.pdf",
                event.getPaymentNumber(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getYear(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getMonthValue(),
                event.getPaymentDate().getDayOfMonth(),
                event.getPaymentNumber());

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(document.length);

        amazonS3.putObject(S3Buckets.CLIENT_PAYMENT_PDF_BUCKET, key, new ByteArrayInputStream(document), metadata);
```

Comment: Файл формируется локально и сохраняется там или формируется тоже там на сервере?
Как проверяете? Скачиваете файл и смотрите локально или открываете прямо там, на сервере?

Comment: Bakhuss, спасибо большое за ответ!
Файл формируется когда сервис работает в кубере.
Пробовал формировать локально из Idea и отправлять на сервер - все работает корректно.
Проверяю скачивая файл из бакета MiniO.

Comment: Проблема с кодировкой кириллицы на сервере.

Comment: Я пробовал явно указывать разные кодировки при формировании файла. Это не решало проблему, к сожалению.
Как еще можно решить эту проблему кодировки?

Comment: Проблема не с кодировкой в приложении, а с кодировкой сервера, где приложение запущено. Сервер с текущими настройками не поддерживает кириллицу.